# poptorootviewcontroller when clicking a button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Let me explain clearly now,

I have a tabbarcontoller in the viewcontroller which is the main view controller of the single view application project.

I added a tabbarcontroller to the viewcontroller as the subview.  In the tabbarcontroller, I added two navigation controllers like below image,

[image]

I have added three(named First, Second, Third) more viewcontrollers as new file.

If I navigate from one viewcontroller to other in the first tab using below code,

```
third =  [[Third alloc] initWithNibName:@"Third" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:third animated:YES];
```

Then I switch to second tab by clicking the tab below the tabbarcontroller.

and then

If I switch to next tab(first tab) by clicking a button in third view controller using,

```
-(IBAction)switchtab
{
    vc.tabctrl.selectedIndex=0;
    //vc is the main viewcontroller to which the tabbarcontoller(tabctrl) added as subview
}
```

After switching to next tab, there I should poptorootviewcontroller, I tried below code

```
-(IBAction)switchtab
{
    vc.tabctrl.selectedIndex=0;
    [vc.tabctrl.navigationController  popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
}
```

But it jumps to next tab but popToViewController not working, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand the whole structure here, but I have realised that you are using different controllers to push the vc "third" and to pop to root. Can you try:

```
[self.navigationController  popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

in the same class you are using to push the "third"?

Edit: Another option, can you try this:

```
-(IBAction)switchtab
{
    vc.tabctrl.selectedIndex=0;
    [(UINavigationController*)vc.tabctrl.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I have two tabs in the tabbarcontroller, I pushed from one viewvontroller to other viewcontroller in the first tab.

Comment: Then I switch to the second tab by clicking the tab button below the tabbarcontroller and I have a button on the second tab's viewcontroller and by clicking that button I should swich to the first tab and as well as popto the first viewcontroller of the first tab.

Comment: I hope you understand, if not please ask, I'm searching for the solution for long time.

Comment: All in All Azahguraja's answer seems to be accurate. Can you set a breakpoint and say if the code stops in the tabBarController:didSelectViewController message?

Comment: I set the breakpoint to the method that All in All Azahguraja suggest, but it gets called when I click the tab, it won't get called if click a UIButton inside the view controller.

Comment: and one more thing I need to convey you, if you want to say anything to someone in other than their posts, please add @theirusername to the comment, I find [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493002/poptorootviewcontroller-when-clicking-a-button#comment28914538_19493344) after 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 3):

If your viewcontroller are of navigation controller then following code will change to root view when you switch the tab

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([self.tabBarController.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        [(UINavigationController*)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    }

}
```

Comment: sorry, it's not working, if I click the button it jump to next tab, but popToViewController not working properly.

Comment: popToRootViewController should work, you do not need to pop to the 0'th viewController. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: This is a UITabBarControllerDelegate method. This will not work if you  don't set the class with this code as the delegate for the tabBarController.

Comment: @All in All Azahguraja, I won't click the tab, I'll click a button inside the viewcontroller of the tabbarcontroller, the above code will only work if I click the tabs

Comment: Improved my answer, try invoking the same code inside switchTab method.

Comment: @All in All Azahguraja, thanks for your time, keep stackoverflowing.

Comment: sure i will  you told that when am switching between tabs so only i posted. sorry.